# Using computed fields module to display certain fields?

Tags: 7, entities

I just installed the [computed fields](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module and I'm a little lost as to how to use it. I have 2 fields in my content type: `field_shortdesc` and `field_audio_description`.

If `field_shortdesc` is blank I need to display `field_audio_description` and vice-versa.

What code do I need to place into the computed code and display code areas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, but this is an issue I struggled with as well.

In the first box, 'Computed Code' you determine the value of the computed field based on what is present in the $entity object. Calculations are possible, but drupal functions or methods are not available. In your case the entire determination can be performed here:

```
if ( isset($entity->field_shortdesc) && trim($entity->field_shortdesc[$entity->language][0]['value']) != "") {
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_shortdesc[$entity->language][0]['value'];
} elseif (isset($entity->field_audio_description)) {
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = :$entity->field_audio_description[$entity->language][0]['value'];
} else {
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = "";
}
```

The second box, 'Display Code', is for processing the value you determined in the first box. If you have to call drupal functions to load a user object or to format text this is where you would do it. In your case, no further processing is required, so you would leave the default:

```
$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];
```

Then if your fields are using an input format (eg. 'Filtered HTML') you will want to set the display format (under 'Manage Display') to 'Filtered markup'.